# Returning the size of mallocatted array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int *num=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    printf("Enter how many numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter numbers:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",num+i);    

    }

    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",*(num+j));    

    }

    return 0;
}
```

How does malloc work even though I have not initialized the n here?And is there any way to check the size of the array that is allocated with malloc?

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Comment: *is there any way to check the size of the array that is allocated with malloc* Nope.

Answer (score -1):

You can add to whole length 1 when allocating and keep n as length in the first element. If you'll want to get something from array just add 1 to index.